# create canvas with adding events to shapes [KineticJs]

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

i'm trying to create a drawing canvas using KineticJs, here's the code on jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/thekucays/k7ZMc/2/

on my code above, i'm trying to create a rect, and add an event listener to every single rect i created.. (line 115)

```
var item = layer.get('.rect1');
item.on('click', function(){
    item.setFill('RED');
});
```

but when i execute it, if i click any rect on the canvas, the event fires on the last rect i created..
what's wrong with my code above?

best regards,
Luki R Rompis

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't work because you don't have references for kinetic.js and kode.js

Answer (score 0):

you were using:

```
 var item = layer.get('.rect1'+rect_counter); //dont user "+rec_counter" as this is what binds it to the LAST element
 item.on('click', function(){
    item.setFill('RED');
 });
```

try a more basic workaround:  -------- This one works best for me -----------

```
 var itemsList = layer.getChildren(); //gets all shapes in this layer
 for(var i=0; i<itemsList.length; i++){
      if(itemsList.getName == 'rect1'){ //since you named your rectangles 'rect1' check name
          itemsList[i].on('click', function(){
             item.setFill('RED');
          });
      }
 };
```

or simply try just using:

```
 var item = layer.get('.rect'); //all rectangles, without number
 item.on('click', function(e){ // I think you need an 'e' here
     item.setFill('RED');
 });
 // I doubt this will work as ALL your rectangles need to have the same name if you want to .get() them all
```

Answer (score 0):

hy :)
umm..yeah on my code, the reason why i used rect_counter is that i want to track the last rect i drawed..so i don't need to start over the loop from the first rect to bind the event..

now i have changed (on the mouseup event) into :

```
var rects = stage.get('.rect'+rect_counter);
rects.on('click', function(){
    this.setAttrs({
        fill: 'red'
    });
    //layer.draw();
});
```

now it works..and so far so good..thanks for your help :)

best regards,

Luki R Rompis